# In operator takes only one Id(if Id is repeating) from the list in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I am using IN operator and I want all the rows from in given list as shown in the picture that I want 3 rows for id 1 and one for id 2, but I only get one row for Id = 1 is there any other solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Provide the sample data and expected output to improve this question. **1.** As far as I understand, seems there is only 1 row with `id` being `1` **2.** Why are you repeating the values (1,2,1,1) while you can simplify it to (1,2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IN` can't do what you want. `JOIN` instead:

```
select * from logs
JOIN (values (1),(2),(1),(1)) x (id)
  ON logs.id = x.id
```